# Select one record per minute group in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a big table in a postgres db with location of units. Now I need to retrieve a location for every 60 seconds.

In Mysql, this is a piece of cake: `select * from location_table where unit_id = '123' GROUP BY round(timestamp / 60)`

But in postgres this seems to be a very hard problem. I also have the timestamps in dateformat rather than in epoch format.

Here is an example of how the table looks

```
CREATE TABLE location_table (
    unit_id int,
    "timestamp" timestamp(3) without time zone NOT NULL,
    lat double precision,
    lng double precision
);
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data and expect result? you use group by but didn't use aggregate function let might be an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use date_trunc() to make sets per minute:

```
SELECT  * -- most likely not what you want
FROM    location_table 
WHERE   unit_id = 123 -- numbers don't need quotes ' 
GROUP BY date_trunc('minute', 'timestamp');
```

The * is of course wrong, but I don't know what you want to know about the GROUP so I can't come up with something better.

Edit:
When you need a random result from your table, DISTINCT ON () could do the job:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON(date_trunc('minute', timestamp))
     * -- your columns
FROM    location_table;
```

There are other (standard SQL) solutions as well, like using row_number().

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I am after is a sample in the group (lat, lng, timestamp)

Comment: @Sebastian: See the update, just one example of several options you have